# EC2 python pickle fails

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, pickle

I'm doing a calculation on EC2 using python and when I try to dump a pickle file containing a dictionary, the program just exists, no error notice or anything. The file is large, around 1 gig, but everything works fine on my laptop, just not on EC2. I'm using an m3.large instance with an attached EBS volume with plenty of space. In the following code snippet, it prints out "dumping now" and then.....nothing, no "dumping complete". No error is caught by 'except'.  When I try to load the pickle file I get an EOF Error.

Thanks for any advice!

```
try:
    fp = open(pickleFile,"wb")
    print 'dumping now'
    pickle.dump(dataDict, fp)
    print 'dumping complete'
    fp.close()
except:
    fp = open('/Users/thisUser/Data/report.txt','w')
    fp.write('error writing pickle file')
    fp.close()
```

Comment: Maybe try dumps (to a string).  That might let you know if it's a serialization issue.  Or if you are worried about the extra memory needed, you can use `dill`, and check if `dill.pickles(dataDict)`.

Comment: probably good to let us know the version number of python you are using, and any other modules you are using, as well as what's in the dataDict.

Answer (score 0):

1. Especially if you're debugging file IO, try not to have your debugging depend on said file IO. If there are any permissions or disk issues, you'll never know since the error message won't be able to write either.
2. Try running `watch "ls -lh /your/file"`, then running your script, to see if the file writing stops suddenly, or is just continuing at a slow pace.
3. Try Ctrl-C if your script is hung and your `watch` looks static, and check out where in the traceback your function is spending its time.
4. Try pickling elements/keys of the dictionary individually--the pickling may be crashing on an individual complex element.
5. Try cPickle
6. Compare your versions at home and on ec2: `import cPickle; print cPickle.__version__`
7. Try different pickling versions.

I'm not sure which of these might help, but one of them might.

Comment: I'd agree with your 1-3, and for the most part with the rest of what you said with one exception.  `cPickle` shouldn't get you any further where `pickle` fails.  Yes, check if the individual items in the dict serialize, and yes try different versions (unlikely, but it could work)… but `pickle/cPickle` should have no difference in objects it can pickle.  Another third-party serializer might get you further, but I'd only go that route if it's indeed a serialization issue coming from one of the objects being passed in `dataDict`.